# Can a L.I. set transform into a L.D. set after Linear Transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $X$ be a real vector space. Suppose $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\} \subset X$ is a linearly independent set, and suppose $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\} \subset X$ is a linearly dependent set. Define $V= \operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ and $W= \operatorname{span}\{w_1, w_2, w_3\}$.

(a) Is there a linear transformation $P : V \to W$ such that $P(v_i) = w_i$ for $i=1,2,3$?

(b) Is there a linear transformation $Q : W \to V$ such that $Q(w_i) = v_i$ for $i=1,2,3$?

What I am thinking is that is this question equivalent to "Can a L.I. set transform into a L.D. set after Linear Transformation ?"(I am a little bit confused about "$P(v_i)=w_i$" is this mean "for every set $V$ and $W$, there exist a linear transformation s.t. ..." ?) If not, then what should be the right solution to this question? Can anyone give me some hints on how to solve this problem？ Thanks!

Comment: Your question in the title is silly: just map everything to the zero vector.

Comment: For part a),can anyone give a simple specific example? I think maybe we need to separate W into three different circumstances: rank=0,rank=1,rank=2. But I still cannot figure out what the linear transformation could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to a) is yes. You have to use the fact that $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ cab be extended to a basis for $X$. Once you have a basis you can give arbitrary values to the basis elements and extend it to a linear function. 
Answer to b): any dependence relation among $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ leads to the same relation among $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ so the answer is no.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but can you explain part a) more specifically? Can we find a specific linear transformation satisfying the condition？

Comment: It is not possible to define the linear transformation explicitly on the whole of X, but on the span of $\{v_1,v_2,v_2\}$ it is defined by $L(av_1+bv_2+cv_3)=aw_1+bw_2+cw_3$

Comment: I am not quite sure about this. This might look a bit general, can we clarify what it dose to every element in its domain?

Answer (score 0):

$P(v_i)=w_i$ means the image of $v_i$ under linear transformation $P$ is $w_i$.

Hint for part b:

Suppose $w_1=c_2w_2+c_3w_3$, then we have $Q(w_1)=c_2Q(w_2)+c_3Q(w_3)$, try to see a contradiction using definition of linearly independence.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification for b), now I know how to solve it.